# Active GPS tracker which also logs BLE beacons in proximity

Tags: gps, tracking-devices, asset-tracking

I'm currently automating a process on our farm: The idea is, that when a machine worked on a field, there's a push notification (or mail) sent to my phone at the end of the day telling me which fields were processed, how long it took etc. All the info I'd usually have to write down manually.

For now, I've been using GT02a GPS/GPRS trackers for the purpose. They are attached to the tractors fuse boxes, and turn on once the tractor is started. However, the interesting info comes with the implements that have been attached to the tractor (plough/seeder/etc.). As often there is no power supply available right on the implement, I would need an additional plug for the GT02 trackers. In practice, these additional plugs are often forgotten to be attached, so it's not really a reliable solution for now.

A (technically) possible alternative would be to add battery powered BLE beacons to the implements, and have a GPS tracker attached to the tractors that also reports on the BLE beacons found in proximity. Basically the same device as the GT02a, but with an additional BLE chip. Also with this technology, I'd like to use my own server/sim cards.
The data the tracker is sending should somewhat look like this (or contain the same info in a different format):

```
{
  imei: 12344566,
  time: // timestamp from the ping
  position: [lat,lng],
  beaconsInReach: [{
   id: 'ble_beacon_id',
   rssi: 70   
  },
  // ... further beacons, their ids, and rssi values
  ]
}
```

Does anyone know about a GPS tracking device capable of this task?

Thanks a lot for you help!

P.S.: The tractors are not equipped with ODB2 ports as typically found in cars.